# Triangulation in R

Tags: python, r, interpolation, triangulation

I am working on an irregular grid with two-dimensional latitude/longitude arrays (providing temperature).
I want to interpolate several points (defined in latitude/longitude, ex: `lat=45.3 N / lon=-2.3 W` in my grid by using triangulation.
I know a function in R : `interp()` that can obtain the temperature value at these points.
But I want to get the latitude/longitude indices in my grid.

ex: Point 1 : `lat=45.3 N , lon=-2.3 W`
    -> indices on my grid `lat= ?, lon= ?`

What function, in either NCL or python can i use?
Thank you

Comment: you want delaunay triangulation, to get an interpolated value at a certain point?

Comment: You should find the new grid points in the results of `interp` (e.g. `result$x` and `result$y`)

Comment: for the moment, I just want to get the matching lat/lon indices on my grid –

Comment: The only fonction I found for triangulation is interp(), but I am a new user of R .. And I did not see that the indices were provided in the results of interp

Comment: The question still does not make sense to me. From the question it seems that lat=45.3 N , lon=-2.3 W is *not* a point in your irregular grid, as you state you want to interpolate the value there, thus what exactly do you mean when you say you want the indices?